# Were all 65,000 frames in Loving Vincent painted separately?

Tags: loving-vincent

Were all 65,000 frames of the movie [Loving Vincent](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3262342/) painted individually or were some of them just modified from the previous frame?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loving_Vincent#Production

Comment: Wikipedia claims 'surface re-use' so that a total of 1000 paintings were done / survived the shooting process.

Comment: @iandotkelly is it not enough to make an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes** and **No**.

YES as in they were painted as separate frame and there is no software inbeetweners or morphing used.

And NO as each frame is not a brand new painting. One of the pros of using oil paint is that is dry very slowly. So they painted "base shot" taken picture and then changed it a little bit. Erased, painted  new thing.

In the gif below you can see that the background is still and only "moving" parts are changed. Near the sleeve you can see how the paint have changed in the background.  (the red corner)
In the upper left part of hat you can see "onioning" so a line from previous take that was painted over but not smoothed with the neighbouring space.so you have line, under line under line.

[image: painting over]

Comment: any source you copied the information from? Kindly mention if any

Comment: @AnkitSharma Few of my friends worked as painters for this movie and we had some talks about technic and production.